# How can I create a class that runs all methods in others classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to create a class that runs every method in a class, I wrote this code below but it is not working and doesnt show any Error message.

```
class RunAll:
    def __init__(self, clss):
        self.methods = []
        self.clss = clss

    def get_methods(self):
        for method in dir(self.clss):
            method = getattr(self.clss, method)
            if callable(method):
                self.methods.append(method)

    def run_all(self):
        self.get_methods()
        for method in self.methods:
            if method.startswith('__'):
                #checks if the method cant run
                continue
            return method()
```

My intention is to use this class in other codes so I dont have to write all the methods every time, like this one:

```
class SayHi:
    def __init__(self, user_name):
        self.name = user_name

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.name}")

    def good_bye(self):
        print(f"Bye {self.name}")

say_hi = SayHi('Steve Rogers')
RunAll(say_hi).run_all()
```

The result should be:

```
Hello Steve Rogers
Bye Steve Rogers
```

Comment: How do you plan to ensure you pass the appropriate parameters to each method given your current design? What *exactly* is your use case that there’s a requirement to invoke every single callable method for a given class?

Comment: Create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how it is not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that none of the class callables either take any parameters or return anything useful? What should happen if one (or more) of the callables raises an [uncaught] exception?

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution, here is the code that works if you need it:

```
class RunAll:
    def __init__(self, class):
        self.methods = []
        self.clss = clss

    def get_methods(self):
        for method in dir(self.clss):
            mtd = getattr(self.clss, method)
            if callable(mtd) and not method.startswith('__'):
                self.methods.append(method)
        self.methods.reverse()

    def run_all(self):
        self.get_methods()
        for method in self.methods:
            getattr(self.clss, method)()
```